# Perfect-scrollbar ran without stopping

Tags: angular, scrollbar, perfect-scrollbar

I installed a perfect-scrollbar on the application Angular 2, and I wrote the following code:
app.modules:

```
import { PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface } from 'angular2-perfect-scrollbar';
const PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
  suppressScrollX: true
};
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    PerfectScrollbarModule.forRoot(PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG),

  ],
...
})
```

Component templete:

```
  <perfect-scrollbar class="container" style="height: 150px;">
  <div class="content">
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
    Scrollable content<br>
    </div>
</perfect-scrollbar>
```

When I bring up the page, I see the scroll bar, but when I start a little scroll, all the content div disappeared.

I tested the tool developers, and saw that the class = "ps-scrollbar-x-rail" and class = "ps-scrollbar-y-Rail" continue to run without stopping, and the right style and top style rising numbers are very high and I can not stop them.
What could be the reason for this strange thing?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

It happens just in chrome browser, in Firefox and Explorer it ok.